# Url rewrite on two login page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I am having some problem when I try to rewrite my login page url.
This is how. I got two Login page, **FirstLoginPage.aspx** and **SecondLoginPage.aspx**,
I wish to rewrite to page to **/FirstAuthen** and **/SecondAuthen**.

Whenever the user wanted to go to the second login page, they must first pass the first login.
I have the following code in my web.config with the default document set to ~/FirstAuthen

```
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="~/FirstAuthen"/>
  </files>
 </defaultDocument>

 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms defaultUrl="~/Home" loginUrl="~/SecondLoginPage.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1440"/>
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>

 <location path="FirstLoginPage.aspx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>  

 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="remove firstlogin" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="FirstAuthen" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="FirstLoginPage.aspx"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="remove secondlogin" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="SecondAuthen" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="SecondLoginPage.aspx"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

and the following code in my Global.asax

```
 Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    'FirstLoginPage
    routes.MapPageRoute("First", "FirstAuthen/", "~/FirstLoginPage.aspx")

    'SecondLoginPage
    routes.MapPageRoute("Second", "SecondAuthen/", "~/SecondLoginPage.aspx")

    'other routes
 End Sub
```

All other rewrite work fine,and firstloginpage will be loaded when the project start. Except the firstloginpage.aspx, it doesn't rewrite to ~/FirstAuthen as I wish. I tried many others way, but no luck. Am I doing anything wrong with the above code? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your rewrite match rule you need to set `/` before the url first, so it should look like this:

> ```
>  <match url="/FirstAuthen" />
> ```

and in your action rule you can redirect your page to another one like below:

> ```
>   <rule name="go to second auth" stopProcessing="true">
>       <match url="/FirstAuthen"/>
>       <action type="Redirect" url="SecondAuthen" redirectType="Permanent"/>
>   </rule>
> ```

and do the same for the other one

Comment: Hi @ali thanks for the reply. I tried with your answer, but no luck. It shows me some kind of error under 401.2 Unauthorized, I guess it something to do with the <location path> that i set in my web config. I tried to change **<location path="FirstLoginPage.aspx">** to **<location path="/FirstAuthen">** it also shows me the same error.

Comment: did you try to remove those locations out and test it with rewrite function only ?

Comment: i didn't remove the location. I will not be able to load the FirstLoginPage if I remove it since deny all user is declared on **<authorization> <allow users="?"/> </authorization>**. But anyway I just tried with what you have mentioned, result is just like what I said. Access denied.